# What is the surface area of part of the given plane?

Tags: surface-integrals

The plane I am given is 3x+2y+z = 6, which lies in the first octant. I am having troubling figuring out my boundaries for the integral to plug into the surface area formula.

Comment: Which integral?

Comment: $3x + xy = 6$ isn't the equation of a plane. Do you mean a surface in general?

Comment: I have corrected the equation, which is 3x+2y+z = 6.